# Is "speed dial" really an obsolete term by now? or is the term here to stay?

Tags: word-usage

This website https://www.wikihow.com/Set-Speed-Dial-on-Android says "speed dial" is *a bit obsolete*, but I don't understand why wikihow.com says this because I can enter phone numbers into my contacts and then choose the very number I'm trying to call within my contacts and then call the number just by pressing one button and there you go. If that is not speed dial, I don't know what is.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/speed-dial :

> speed-dial
>
> in British English
>
> (ˈspiːdˌdaɪəl)
>
> verb
>
> to call (someone) on a telephone by pressing a single button rather than by dialling the full number
>
> Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers

Even though you have to go through your contacts first, you are still not dialing the full number. Does turning the phone on also count as an extra button to press along with pressing the contact button afterwards? Does turning your phone on and then pressing contacts and choosing a contact really have to count in order to disqualify the next step as speed dial? The next step is not dialing seven numbers, it is just pressing one button.

Comment: "Speed dial" is when you can press one button to call a particular number without having to find the right entry in your contacts list first.

Comment: *Anachronistic* might be a better term than *obsolete*. There is no dial on the Android, so "speed dial" is a throwback to an earlier era when phones had dials.

Comment: @rajah9 - I suggest that, while it's true that "dial" is anachronistic in modern telephony, that's not what Edna is asking. She's wondering about the feature (anachronistically) called *speed dial*, and whether that feature has become obsolete. Weather Vane rightly eulogizes it: there's no longer a need to identify your Top Ten friends when you can reach them all with the press of a button. Yet another Seinfeld episode premise bites the dust.

Comment: I think there's a difference between contact lists and speed dial, even though they can accomplish similar things. Speed dial assigns the task of dialing specified numbers to specific buttons (or other controls/UI elements) to save typing. Contact lists are lists of people's details with phone number, email, address, usernames, etc; many phones will let you maintain multiple contact lists and contact them in different ways when you view the list. Contact lists have automated the process of looking up a phone number and dialing; speed dial was an earlier alternative when that wasn't possible.

Comment: What used to be called "speed dial" is now a short list of "favorites".

Comment: And rather than having a button for each of them, we used assistants like Siri or Alexa.